# ¿Cómo puedo saber cuáles son las filas duplicadas con Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy trabajando con Pandas y la función [`duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) para detectar filas que son iguales.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    1: {'nombre': 'n1', 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30},
    2: {'nombre': 'n2', 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30},
    3: {'nombre': 'n3', 1: 11, 2: 21, 3: 30},
    4: {'nombre': 'n4', 1: 11, 2: 21, 3: 30},
    5: {'nombre': 'n5', 1: 12, 2: 22, 3: 30},
    6: {'nombre': 'n6', 1: 13, 2: 22, 3: 30},
    7: {'nombre': 'n7', 1: 14,        3: 35},
    8: {'nombre': 'n8',        2: 22, 3: 35},
}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d).transpose().set_index('nombre')
```

Esto me da un precioso data frame tal que así:

```
          1    2   3
nombre              
n1       10   20  30    # igual que n2
n2       10   20  30    # igual que n1
n3       11   21  30    # igual que n4
n4       11   21  30    # igual que n3
n5       12   22  30
n6       13   22  30
n7       14  NaN  35
n8      NaN   22  35
```

Ahora quiero agrupar las líneas cuyas columnas coincidan. Esto es, quiero que pandas me diga que las filas de valor `n1` y `n2` son iguales y lo mismo con `n3`-`n4`.

Usando `duplicated()` obtengo algo muy interesante:

```
df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Es decir:

```
         1   2   3
nombre            
n1      10  20  30
n2      10  20  30
n3      11  21  30
n4      11  21  30
```

Que es correcto, pues detecta cuáles son las filas que tienen duplicados. Sin embargo, lo que realmente me interesa es saber cuáles son esas columnas, así como cuáles son los pares duplicados. Es decir, necesitaría obtener un resultado del tipo `[(n1, n2), (n3,n4)]` (una lista con las tuplas duplicadas entre sí.

Busco y busco en la documentación de pandas y no consigo encontrar algo así. Probé con [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) pero no consigo nada razonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Traducción de la [respuesta dada por jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48904523/6836377) a la misma [pregunta planteada en SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48904448/1983854)</sub>

Puedes usar [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) para agrupar todas las columnas. Luego conviertes los índices a una lista para cada uno de los grupos. Finalmente, conviertes un objeto tipo `Series` a la lista final que esperas:

```
df1 = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]

df1 = df1.groupby(df1.columns.tolist()).apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist()).values.tolist()
print (df1)
[['n1', 'n2'], ['n3', 'n4']]
```

Detalle del Series:

```
print (df1.groupby(df1.columns.tolist()).apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist()))
1   2   3 
10  20  30    [n1, n2]
11  21  30    [n3, n4]
dtype: object
```

Comment: ¡Gracias Patricio por incorporar la respuesta!

Comment: @fedorqui, faltaba más! es una muy buena respuesta.